# Bibliography style and line breaks in Beamer-poster

Tags: latex, beamer, bibtex

I'm making a poster through beamer and found a problem with my bibliography style. I want my references to use the full horizontal space available in the poster, like:

```
(1) Authors. Title. Journal.
```

But instead of that, every reference get breaked in 3 lines as:

```
(1) Authors

    Title

    Journal
```

### Example

[image: Figure]

Here's the bibliography code I've been using:

```
\begin{block}{References}
\small
\bibliographystyle{sbc}
\bibliography{referencias.bib}
\end{block}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line breaks can be avoided by setting the bibliography templates like this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry article}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry article}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{knuth}
\begin{block}{References}
\small
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{block} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you :)

Comment: @GabrielLucas I thank you for asking a question involving beamer! They are my favourite questions!